# How to print the content in RichTextBox in FoxPro

Tags: printing, richtextbox, visual-foxpro

I have searched the web about the topic but all I have found is the VB and C# solutions.  Does anybody know if there is a way in VFP 9 to print out the content in the RichTextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fox pro codes enables a function called selprint which can be used to print the contents of RTB

```
    cdlPDReturnDC=256
    cdlPDNoPageNums=8
    cdlPDSelection=1
    cdlPDAllPages=0

    Thisform.CommDlg1.Flags = cdlPDReturnDC + cdlPDNoPageNums
    If Thisform.RTF1.SelLength = 0
    Thisform.CommDlg1.Flags = Thisform.CommDlg1.Flags ;
    + cdlPDAllPages
    Else
    Thisform.CommDlg1.Flags = Thisform.CommDlg1.Flags ;
    + cdlPDSelection
    EndIf
    Thisform.CommDlg1.ShowPrinter
    Thisform.RTF1.SelPrint(Thisform.CommDlg1.hDC)
```